# Integrate django rest auth with django allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am trying to integrate [django rest auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth) with [django allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth).
I installed them both as their documentation says and I have issue with configuring the routes.
This is what I made in my urls file:

```
urlpatterns = [
  re_path(r'^auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
  re_path(r'^auth/signup/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
  ...
]
```

The registration works fine, but on my confirmation email that I receive there is a link. Clicking on that link gives 500 status code with the following exception:

```
TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'
```

What did I do wrong? how should I configure django rest auth and django allauth? Is there any tutorial that provide step by step instructions (I am new to django)?

Comment: Can you share the full traceback? Which versions of Django and allauth are you using?